# узнать информацию о usb-флешке

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb

мне надо узнать информацию о флешке, зная лишь букву диска (конкретно нужно знать имя и размер минимум). То есть я подключаю **любую** флешку и я узнаю метку тома (это уже сделано), потом узнаёт информацию о ней

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите библиотеку [WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/)

```
pip install WMI
```

Так можно получить информацию для конкретного логического диска:

```
import wmi
letter = 'E'
usb = wmi.WMI(moniker=f'//./root/cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="{letter}:"')
print(usb)

print(usb.VolumeName)
print(usb.size)
```

Выведет:

```
instance of Win32_LogicalDisk
{
    Access = 0;
    Caption = "E:";
    Compressed = FALSE;
    CreationClassName = "Win32_LogicalDisk";
    Description = "Съемный диск";
    DeviceID = "E:";
    DriveType = 2;
    FileSystem = "FAT32";
    FreeSpace = "26245922816";
    MaximumComponentLength = 255;
    Name = "E:";
    Size = "30925651968";
    SupportsDiskQuotas = FALSE;
    SupportsFileBasedCompression = FALSE;
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
    SystemName = "DESKTOP-9MC4P8S";
    VolumeDirty = FALSE;
    VolumeName = "ESD-USB";
    VolumeSerialNumber = "B28D95A4";
};

ESD-USB
30925651968
```